# Using Kendo.dataSource in Karma tests

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, jasmine, karma-runner

So i'm wondering if anyone has been able to mock the ajax call made by Kendo's dataSource object.  During testing I receive this warning

```
WARN [web-server]: 404: ...
```

Here's a screenie
[image]

It's basically the transport.read trying to get the data for the chart.  I've tried to use $httpBackend to resolve this request but I still get the warning.  While it's not failing any tests it's really annoying to see.  Here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yaT5pxt26BULWqmTU71M?p=preview)

Comment: I failed to find how you implemented your tests. I have used kendo-ui along with Karma/Jasmine/Angular if it makes you feel any better :).

Comment: Well I guess the pulnkr doesn't actually run the jasmine test...I wasn't able to get it to go successfully but it's there more so to see how all the code works together.  It's not a problem of getting the code to work but more of how to "capture" kendo.dataSource's reads so that I don't get the warnings...  If I need to get the tests running on the plunkr to help you understand that better I could definately use some help..... Oh and the screenshot is the actual implementation.  The plunkr has the data at the root level.

Comment: Is my question clear enough or do I need to add more detail?  To respond more to @Dalorzo the tests run just fine as you can see by the output of my screenshot.  And the question is not one about how to make the tests run...but it's a question on how to mock the fetch calls that kendo.DataSource makes.  Please help!

Comment: I do not understand what is what you are trying to test or how. Please check this site it may help http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/#/basics

Comment: @Dalorzo I think I understand what you're asking.  I'm not trying to test anything specific in this post (per-se) but rather trying to figure out how to capture the GET that is being made by the kendo datasource.  Because the dataSource is trying to fetch my JSON data it is making some GET call and causing the warning to happen that I mentioned as part of the original question.  I'm not trying to test the call or that the data is linked properly but more trying to squelch the warning.  I'm used to $httpBackend or spies but none of those work.

Comment: I've updated the plunkr to show some of the different approaches i've tried.